# No more handles [Could not detect registered XULRunner to use]

Tags: java, browser, swt, eclipse-rcp, xulrunner

I am using SWT 3.7 to create an RCP application. Windows is my OS and IE is set as the default SWT browser. I want to change the default browser from IE to Mozilla. I've read a few articles and learned that by adding arguments to the `eclipse.ini` file (`-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla`) one can set the default SWT browser.

But after adding it to vm arguments (because when adding to the .ini file it is not doing anything), I get the error below:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [Could not detect registered XULRunner to use]
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4308)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.create(Mozilla.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Browser.java:99)
```

The code is breaking on line:

```
Browser browser = new Browser(parent, SWT.None);
```

I have already downloaded xulrunner, ran the register command, checked in registry (it's there), added `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath="C://Program Files (x86)//Mozilla XULRunner//1.9.1//xulrunner"` to vmargs but I still get the same error.

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: Why the double slashes (`//`) in the `XULRunnerPath`?

Comment: Escape character in window

Comment: You only have to escape backslashes with another backslash afaik.

Answer (score 1):

Found this in the eclipse forum:

"Found the problem. I needed to do xulrunner --register-global as administrator. Since there is no difference in the xulrunner output, the only way to tell if the registration occurred is to look in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\mozilla.org\GRE"

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/199032/#msg_634819